# create a postgresql dump file on ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1

I am new to the ubuntu environment and I want to create the dump file of an database. Can any one help me to take the postgres dump file on ubuntu system

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

/usr/bin/pg_dumpall --host {yourhost} --port {port} --username "{username}" --database "{dbname}" --no-password  --verbose --file "backup.sql"

Comment: tried above cmd but got the error "pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "events""

Comment: if you don't specify a DB username, pg_dumpall uses the calling OS username as a default. It this user doesn't exist, or you enter the wrong password for the DB you will get this error.
Try adding "-U postgres" to connect as postgres user